# Simple SQL Server Update query taking over 15 mins

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table which contains 5 columns and 3 rows. Schema description:

- `cId` (`int`) is the id of the table it is not autonumeric but its values are 1-2-3 for now.
- `cIdFoot` (`int`) is the foreign key from another static data table that has 4 rows.
- `cwId` (`int`) It is another foreign key from a table with lots of columns but just 1 row.
- 2 description columns which are of type `varchar(MAX)`

Although `cIdFoot` and `cwId` are both foreign keys since they are nearly empty tables in this table those are currently not created as foreign keys.

My update is this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET desc1 = '2018', desc2 = '2018'
WHERE (cId = 1)
```

This simple SQL script takes over 6 mins and the table just has 3 rows.

Doing selects seems ok but when I try to update it takes forever and it usually times out. I have seen that in the log -> .ldf file does not seem to get any bigger, could it be that it has been corrupted or that it was not created well. Strangely bigger tables with over 10000 rows work correctly when updating or inserting.

Any help would be grateful.

The execution plan: [The Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edItP.png)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something is blocking it. run [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) when you run your update and see what the blocker is for that session.

Comment: Seems like my query is in suspended status. suspended, spid: 108 ecid: 0 status: suspended loginame: sa hostname: PC blk: 85 dbname: database cmd: UPDATE request_id: 0

Comment: ok, there are a few reasons why it could be suspended, like being blocked. can you post the results of the sp_WhoIsActive?

Comment: Let's see the who is Active: I am not putting the ones that are not from my DataBase.spid: 85 ecid: 0 status: suspended loginname: lp hostname: NSPS blk: 0 dbname: database cmd: SELECT request_id: 0
spid: 108 ecid: 0 status: suspended loginame: sa hostname: PC blk: 85 dbname: database cmd: UPDATE request_id: 0
spid: 155 ecid: 0 status: suspended loginame: lp hostname: NSPS blk: 0 dbname: database cmd: SELECT request_id: 0
spid: 206 ecid: 0 status: suspended loginame: lp hostname: NSPS blk: 0 dbname: database cmd: SELECT request_id: 0
The only running one is a select from sa to master DB.

Comment: Now that I am looking at it more thoughtfully, could it be that the spID 85 is blocking my spid 108 which is the simple Update I am doing. If so, if I kill/finish the SQL Select command that is blocking my table would the update be fast again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, SPID 85 is blocking your update query. Your update will not finish until what ever this process is doing completes or releases the lock it has, which your update needs.

If you kill SPID 85, the update will run, but you need to figure out what this process is doing and why it's holding a lock on that table. It's not likely going to stop obtaining a lock on this table (and thus blocking your update) until you fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I think we were writing the answer in the same time as I did not see your answer, I will put here the interesting SQL and delete my answer. The used SQL: SELECT spid, ecid, loginame, hostname, blocked, 
CASE WHEN dbid = 0 THEN null ELSE db_name(dbid) END as dbname, cmd, request_id 
FROM sysprocesses
WHERE db_name(dbid) LIKE 'myDataBase'